# is there any way to insert a node at the begin of the JSON file?

Tags: json, ruby, file, insert, append

is there any way to insert a node at the begin of the JSON file?

```
jsonArray = JSON.parse(File.open(JSON_filePath).read)
jsonArray << node_to_insert

File.open(JSON_FilePath,"w") do |f|
   f.write(JSON.pretty_generate(jsonArray))
end
```

The script inserts ok, but at the end of the file, I would like to insert at the begin like a first record in the JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

To add your node to insert first instead of last, why not flip the order of your first two lines (with minor alterations)?

```
jsonArray = [node_to_insert] # initialize to array with your first row
jsonArray.push( *JSON.parse(File.open(JSON_filePath).read) ) # push results,
               # use the splat operator (*) to avoid array nesting
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<<` use [Array#prepend](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-prepend). This will insert/prepend instead of append.

```
jsonArray = JSON.parse(File.open(JSON_filePath).read)
jsonArray.prepend(node_to_insert)
```

Comment: Also we can use: 

`jsonArray.unshift(node_to_insert)`